# Why won't the .txt file save in the internal storage?

Tags: java, android, directory, saving-data

I can create and share a .txt file using the following code:

```
File path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Folder");
if (!path.exists()) {
    path.mkdirs();
}

File exportFile = new File(path, fileName);
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(exportFile);
writer.append(body);
writer.flush();
writer.close();

Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(exportFile));
startActivity(intent);
```

However I would like this file to be saved to the app's folder rather than on the SD card directly so I changed to the code below. It doesn't seem to work as it doesn't create the file and any app I try to export to can't see the file.

```
File path = new File(this.getFilesDir(), "exports");
if(!path.exists()){
    path.mkdir();
}
```

Any ideas? Every thing I have tried doesn't work. The file is supposed to be saved in the Android/data/[package name] folder yes?

EDIT: Okay I couldn't get this working but actually found this wasn't the method I wanted to use, I wanted to save the file in the Android/data folder and for that I needed to use:

```
getExternalFilesDir(null)
```

Comment: The file constructor you're using is interpreting "exports" as a file name, not a folder name.  Not sure if this is causing your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check

```
ContextWrapper contextWrapper = new ContextWrapper(context);
File file = contextWrapper.getDir("media", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

And also make sure whether you have necessary permission in your `manifest` file

Answer (score 0):

1. check for permissions in your AndroidManifest.xml
2. check for Directory availability
3. check for availability of external storage
4. check for filename. It must not contain spaces
5. check for permissions to be able to write in that folder